# SQL - Aggregate sql query

Tags: sql

I have to table named `CollecteEncombrants_Terrain` and `CollecteEncombrants_Stops` with the following structure.

[image]

[image]

The `name` column in `CollecteEncombrants_Stops` contains the `globalid` from `CollecteEncombrants_Terrain`.

I would like to select the entity in `CollecteEncombrants_Terrain` with the maximum `sequence` from `CollecteEncombrants_Stops` from all the entities where column `collecteFaite` is not null.

I tried the following query but it returns empty selection:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CollecteEncombrants_Terrain 
WHERE globalid = (SELECT name 
                  FROM CollecteEncombrants_Stops 
                  WHERE sequence = (SELECT MAX(sequence) 
                                    FROM CollecteEncombrants_Stops 
                                    WHERE name IN (SELECT globalid 
                                                   FROM CollecteEncombrants_Terrain 
                                                   WHERE collecteFaite IS NOT NULL)))
```

Comment: A structure of a table cannot (and/or should not) be expressed by a picture. ([Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: @Luuk Yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to select the entity in CollecteEncombrants_Terrain with
> the maximum sequence from CollecteEncombrants_Stops from all the
> entities where column collecteFaite is not null.

Start with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CollecteEncombrants_Terrain 
WHERE collecteFaite is not null
```

add the link to `CollecteEncombrants_Stops`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CollecteEncombrants_Terrain ct
INNER JOIN CollecteEncombrants_Stops cs on cs.name = ct.globalid
WHERE collecteFaite is not null
```

After that add the appropriate filter by adding stuff to the WHERE-clause.

EDIT: To filter on max sequence, which means you are only interested in max sequence values,  you can do:

```
SELECT ct.*, cs.sequence
FROM CollecteEncombrants_Terrain ct
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, max(sequence) as sequenct
            FROM CollecteEncombrants_Stops 
            GROUP BY name) cs on cs.name = ct.globalid
WHERE collecteFaite is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as Im not familiar with SQL queries, I still dont get how to filter on the MAX(sequence) when using INNER JOIN like in your suggestion.